# Picking $3$ points in the edges of a tetrahedron, is the intersection of the triangle with the height a notable point?

Tags: geometry

In a regular tetrahedron $ABCD$, if we pick three points $M$, $N$ and $L$ in the edges $DA$, $DB$ and $DC$, is the intersection of the tetrahedron's height $DH$ with the triangle $MNL$ a notable point of this triangle?

I know that in the similar case with a right trihedron, this intersection is the orthocenter of the triangle, so I am trying to prove in the tetrahedron that it would be something like the baricenter.

Answer (score 1):

Changing notation slightly, consider arbitrary $OA_1 B_1 C_1$ and $O A_2 B_2 C_2$ such that $O$ lies on $\overleftrightarrow{A_1 A_2}$, $\overleftrightarrow{B_1 B_2}$, , and $\overleftrightarrow{B_1 B_2}$. Treating the points as position vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with $O$ at the origin, define points $P_i$, in the respective planes of $\triangle A_i B_i C_i$, using barycentric coordinates:
$$P_i := \frac{\alpha_i A_i + \beta_i B_i + \gamma_i C_i}{\alpha_i + \beta_i + \gamma_i}$$

(where $\alpha_i + \beta_i + \gamma_i \neq 0$). One can readily verify that $O$ lies on $\overleftrightarrow{P_1P_2}$ if and only if

> $$ \frac{a_1 \alpha_1}{a_2 \alpha_2} = \frac{b_1 \beta_1}{b_2 \beta_2} = \frac{c_1 \gamma_1}{c_2 \gamma_2} \tag{$\star$}$$

where
$$a_i := |OA_i| \qquad b_i := |OB_i| \qquad c_i := |OC_i|$$

Now, in a regular tetrahedron, all sides are congruent. Also, the foot of the altitude from a vertex is the centroid of the opposite face. Therefore, if $OA_1B_1C_1$ is regular with altitude $\overline{OP_1}$, then $a_1 = b_1 = c_1$ and $\alpha_1 = \beta_1 = \gamma_1$, so that $(\star)$ reduces to
$$a_2 \alpha_2 = b_2 \beta_2 = c_2 \gamma_2 \qquad\to\qquad
\alpha_2:\beta_2:\gamma_2 \;=\; \frac1{a_2}:\frac1{b_2}:\frac1{c_2} \tag{1}$$
Defining
$$d_i := |B_i C_i| \qquad e_i := |C_i A_i| \qquad f_i := |A_iB_i|$$
we have, for $O$ the vertex of a regular tetrahedron (that is, for $O$ with all face-angles of measure $60^\circ$),
$$d_2^2 = b_2^2+c_2^2-2b_2c_2\cos 60^\circ = b_2^2+c_2^2-b_2c_2 \quad \text{etc}$$
From these, we can, in principle, express $a_2$, $b_2$, $c_2$ in terms of the sides of $\triangle A_2 B_2 C_2$, thus determining whatever "notable" nature $P_2$ has with respect to that triangle. However, it turns out that $a_2^2$, $b_2^2$, $c_2^2$ are roots of quartic polynomials, so finding explicit expressions is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

I'll note that, more generally (and temporarily suppressing subscripts), if $OABC$ is an *arbitrary* tetrahedron with altitude $\overline{OP}$, then

$$\begin{align}
\alpha :\beta: \gamma \;=\;&\quad 
2 (-a^2 d^2 + b^2 e^2 + c^2 f^2) - (-d^2 + b^2 + c^2 ) (-d^2 + e^2 + f^2) \\
&: 2 (\phantom{-}a^2 d^2 - b^2 e^2 + c^2 f^2) - (\phantom{-}a^2 - e^2 + c^2) (\phantom{-}d^2 - e^2 + f^2) \\
&:2 (\phantom{-}a^2 d^2 + b^2 e^2 - c^2 f^2) - (\phantom{-}a^2 + b^2 - f^2) (\phantom{-}d^2 + e^2 - f^2)
\end{align} \tag{2}$$
On the other hand, if $P$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$, then
$$\alpha : \beta : \gamma \;=\; \frac{1}{-d^2+e^2+f^2} : \frac{1}{d^2 - e^2 + f^2}:\frac{1}{d^2 + e^2 - f^2} \tag{3}$$

Further assuming that $OABC$ is an ["orthocentric" (or "orthogonal")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_tetrahedron) tetrahedron, its edges satisfy 
$$a^2 + d^2 = b^2 + e^2 = c^2 + f^2 = m^2$$
for some $m$. As a result, the foot-of-altitude's barycentric coordinates $(2)$ *match* the orthocenter's barycentric coordinates $(3)$:
$$\alpha :\beta: \gamma \;=\; \frac{1}{m^2-(-a^2+b^2+c^2)} 
: \frac{1}{m^2-(a^2-b^2+c^2)} : \frac{1}{m^2-(a^2+b^2-c^2)} \tag{4}$$
In particular, a "right-corner" tetrahedron (defined as having three mutually-perpendicular edges at $O$) is orthocentric, with $m^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$, whence
$$\alpha :\beta: \gamma \;=\; \frac{1}{a^2} 
: \frac{1}{b^2} : \frac{1}{c^2} \tag{5}$$

For $\overline{OP_1}$ to be an altitude from the right-corner vertex $O$ of $OA_1B_1C_1$, and for $P_2$ to be an orthocenter of $\triangle A_2B_2C_2$, then $(\star)$ would require
$$\frac{1/a_1}{1/a_2} = \frac{1/b_1}{1/b_2} = \frac{1/c_1}{1/c_2} \quad\to\quad \frac{a_1}{a_2} = \frac{b_1}{b_2} = \frac{c_1}{c_2} \tag{6}$$
This only occurs when $OA_1B_1C_1$ and $OA_2B_2C_2$ are homothetic with respect to $O$. So, OP's statement ...

> [I]n the similar case with a right trihedron, this intersection [of $\triangle A_2B_2C_2$ with the altitude to $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$] is the orthocenter of [$\triangle A_2B_2C_2$].

... is correct only when the planes of $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$ and $\triangle A_2B_2C_2$ are parallel. (Unless OP's "right trihedron" means something other than my "right-corner tetrahedron".)